# Xamarin - Access to first Resource is throwing an exception

Tags: xamarin, exception, embedded-resource

Visual Studio 2019 (16.3.4), Xamarin Forms 4.2.0.848062

I have the following in my Log On page:

```
<Entry 
    x:Name="Email" 
    StyleClass="Contrast"
    Text="{Binding Email}" 
    Placeholder="{x:Static resources:ApplicationResources.Email}" 
    HeightRequest="45"
    Keyboard="Email" />
```

My Resources are in a separate project and marked as "Embedded Resource".  The Resources work fine including the one above.  However, this one just happens to be the first Resource I access.  It throws an exception:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Invalid Image'
```

on the following "Auto generated code" line in the Designer:

```
/// <summary>
///   Looks up a localized string similar to e-mail.
/// </summary>
public static string Email {
    get {
        return ResourceManager.GetString("Email", resourceCulture); // Exception here
    }
}
```

Continuing on from the Exception and the resource string appears in the PlaceHolder as expected.

If I remove that PlaceHolder code, the same thing happens on the next Resource.  But it only happens on the first Resource I access and it seems to work anyway?!?!?!

Why is it throwing the Exception at all?

Comment: Why are your resources marked as Embedded Resource? If they are C# resources, like in this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/xaml-markup-extensions#the-xstatic-markup-extension,
then it seems they should be in a C# code file and marked with Build Action compile? It might also be worth seeing your xml namespace declaration for "resources". Did you set the assembly name and the namespace? e.g. xmlns:resources="clr-namespace:YourNameSpace;assembly=YourOtherProjectsAssemblyName"

Comment: Yes.  Definitely have the namespace declaration.  It was marked as "Embedded Resource" by default.  Changed it to "Compile", but still the first time the Resources are accessed (even though it works) they throw the Exception.

Comment: My header looks like this:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:resources="clr-namespace:MyApp.Resources;assembly=MyApp.Resources"  
    xmlns:configuration="clr-namespace:MyApp.Mobile.Configuration;assembly=MyApp.Mobile"  
    x:Class="MyApp.Mobile.Pages.LogOnPage">

Comment: Still happening.  Just the first time a resource is accessed.  Program works ok though...